# Delete last n characters from lines within file

Tags: text-processing, macos

I am using a Mac terminal (bash) and I have a file called `data_list.txt` that contains `n` lines as follows:

```
aaabbbccc_7777.txt 
nnhhaa_8888.txt 
ayquabay_9999.txt 
ayqynbnbn_1122.txt 
ooppaa_3454.txt
```

**How can I remove the last 8 characters of each line?**

Expected output of `data_list.txt`:

```
aaabbbccc_ 
nnhhaa_ 
ayquabay_ 
ayqynbnbn_ 
ooppaa_
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are the spaces part of the input?

Comment: Please specify if you want to get rid of whatever is after last 'underline' char...
If that is the case, the better script would be: `sed 's/\(.*_\).*$/\1/' data_list.txt`.
This will work even if you have multiple underlines '_' in one line, because sed is 'gready'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution with sed (note that this is for MacOS):

```
sed -i '' 's/.\{8\}$//' data_list.txt
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to delete the last 8 characters, or all of them if there are fewer  than 8, you could do:

```
sed "s/.\{0,8\}$//; /^$/d" data_list.txt
```

No need for extended regex. This will clear as many characters as it can, but no more than 8. If that leaves an empty line, it'll be removed from the output.

If you need to clear any trailing whitespace (without including it in the 8 characters), you could do:

```
sed "s/.\{0,8\}[[:space:]]*$//" data_list.txt
```

I can only guess what the actual condition is for what should be removed at the end (e.g., everything after the underscore, or a number + the extension), but if you want to strip the file extension and any digits before it:

```
sed "s/[[:digit:]]*\..*$//" data_list.txt
```

Other answers have already shown how to remove everything after the underscore, so I won't repeat that.

Answer (score 5):

To your exact input (all the lines at their ends have white space, except last line) you can use this (I suppose you want get rid of 'after _ part':

```
sed 's/........ *$//' data_list.txt
```

For getting rid of anything after last 'underline' character use this one:

```
sed 's/\(.*_\).*$/\1/' data_list.txt
```

It will also work on lines that have multiple 'underline' characters, because sed is 'greedy'. Although I don't not know if this will work on MacOS, at least this will be useful for feauture Linux sed users that google search engine will land here...

Comment: I see no reason why this should not work on MacOS. But future `sed` users could learn from an explanation of your second command and why you did not use `s/_[^_]*$/_/` instead.

Comment: Technically, the trailing space you are also trimming would usually also count as characters but the OP seems to agree this is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an `awk` solution that's just as fast as frippe's `sed` approach, using an example file with 100,000 lines:

```
time awk '{print substr($0, 1, length($0)-8)}' 100k.txt

real    0m4.110s
user    0m0.142s
sys     0m0.422s

time sed "s/.\{0,8\}$//; /^$/d" 100k.txt

real    0m4.043s
user    0m1.558s
sys     0m0.345s
```

Replace `8` with any number. The main difference here is that `awk` will print a newline if your trim length exceeds your line length, whereas `sed` will not.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -ne '.trim-trailing.chop(8).put;'
```

OR

```
raku -pe '.=trim-trailing; .=chop(8);'
```

Sample Input:

```
wxxyyyzzzz_1234.txt
aaabbbccc_7777.txt 
nnhhaa_8888.txt 
ayquabay_9999.txt 
ayqynbnbn_1122.txt 
ooppaa_3454.txt
```

Sample Output:

```
wxxyyyzzzz_
aaabbbccc_
nnhhaa_
ayquabay_
ayqynbnbn_
ooppaa_
```

Note both answers above use Raku's `trim-trailing` routine to get rid of trailing whitespace. Feel free to delete `trim-trailing` and/or adjust the number of characters `chop`-ped from the right-hand end of the string.

https://docs.raku.org/routine/chop
https://raku.org